# Multiple projects support and dynamic configuration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I would like to implement next thing:

1. Connect to couple of my servers.
2. Fetch Firebase property list file (with necessary data to configure FIRApp).
3. Perform "FirebaseApp.configure(....)" for each of them.
4. Start receive notifications.

So here are my open questions:

1. May I support multiple firebase projects and receive notifications as usually? (each project for each customer).
2. May I dynamically configure FirebaseApp? Not in the appDelegate method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: UPD:
Yes, It's possible to use multiple FIRProjects for cloud messaging. There is no difference where to configure those projects. You can do it anywhere you want :)

If you're facing some troubles around that topic - do not forget, that you're able to have only one instance of Messaging object and you'll need to specify the sender identifier, when fetching the FCM token.
Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: senderID)
Messaging delegate method didReceiveRegistrationToken - will fire only with default firebase application.